# How to force the first char of the directory edit box upper case?

Tags: inno-setup

While running Inno Setup, I have the need of making sure the drive letter of the install directory is uppercase after being entered by a user.

The reason: Apache's [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) requires it. It doesn't work (in httpd.conf) if the drive letter is entered in lower case. And only the drive letter must be changed; Apache can't handle it either if any characters of a path don't match the case of the path in the file system (despite Windows being case-insensitive).

How do I make the Inno Setup `{app}` constant automatically capitalize its first character?

Comment: But wait, do you want to keep the directory edit's first letter upper case or the `{app}` constant ?

Comment: If the directory edit's first letter is forced to upper case in the wizard, doesn't that guarantee the {app} constant to also have its first letter upper case?

Comment: Yeah, definitely! I don't know what I was thinking about when writing that comment. Then it's enough to keep it in the edit box's change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code should keep the first letter of the directory edit box always upper case:

```
[Code]
procedure DirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  SelStart: Integer;
  SelLength: Integer;  
begin
  S := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
  if Length(S) > 0 then
  begin
    SelStart := WizardForm.DirEdit.SelStart;
    SelLength := WizardForm.DirEdit.SelLength;
    Insert(UpperCase(S[1]), S, 2);  
    Delete(S, 1, 1);
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := S;
    WizardForm.DirEdit.SelStart := SelStart;
    WizardForm.DirEdit.SelLength := SelLength;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.DirEdit.OnChange := @DirEditChange;
end;
```